# Change path FileOutputStream Android

Tags: android, path, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to recover a file that I just created in my phone by my app. I know where it is and I saw the File but I need to send it by mail or something like that. When I tried to send the file, permissions were denied. Maybe can I change the folder to get a easier access? Or how Can I get that file out from my phone without connecting to my computer?

Comment: Where did you put this file?

Comment: File is generated bycode and its save in the default folder that is data/data/[project_name]/files/file.txt

Comment: I don't understand, You want to send file from your app or from Android File Manager?

Comment: from anywherem, if I can send from my app will be great but when I tried to send it my app says that permmissions were denied. I Imagine that is because is in a forbiden folder or something like that.

Comment: No it's not, Did you added this permission. 
'code' <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: You must to add android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE so you can read from sdcard, Hope this help.

Comment: I will try. Thank you. while sending the file if I keep writing can not be sent?

Comment: Doesn't work. couldn't send attachment or Gmail has unfortunetly stoped

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to write and here the code to send by mail.

```
        public void saveInfo( String data )
    {
        if( directorio != null )
        {
            FileOutputStream os = null;
            try
            {
                File  f = new File("Datos.txt");
                os = openFileOutput(f.getName(), Context.MODE_APPEND);
                os.write(data.getBytes());
                os.close();
            }   
            catch( Exception e )
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Se produjo un error al momento d escribir el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
       else
        {
           Toast.makeText(this, "No se encuentra ninguna tarjeta SD en el dispositivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Now the send data code

```
    public void sendEmailData( )
{
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"nanodan47@gmail.com"}); // recipients
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Datos");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Adjunto encuentra los datos.");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("data/data/com.example.android.Bluetooth/files/Datos.txt" ) );
    startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```